# Referencing Shared Calendar through 64 Bit Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office365

We have created a VBA script to extract 'Shared Calendars' from MS Outlook, by the click of a button in an Excel Sheet (the shared calendar privileges have been granted) . While the code works well on the developers system, it fails to work on other system. The error that it shows is:
[image]

The code refers to the the following references from Outlook 16 libraries:
[image]

Please suggest what could be the reason for the code to not work. One of the reasons that we think could be that the developer has the 32 Bit Version of Office 365 & others have 64 Bit Version of the same.

Attaching the code for your reference below:

```
Sub ListAppointments()
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olNS As Object
    Dim olFolder As Object
    Dim olApt As Object
    Dim NextRow As Long
    Dim FromDate As Date
    Dim ToDate As Date
    Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myNameSPace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim k, q As Long
    Dim abc(), fDate, tDate As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Sheets("Main").Select
    fDate = Range("B2").Value
    tDate = Range("C2").Value
    FromDate = CDate(fDate)
    ToDate = CDate(tDate)
    
    Sheets("Associates").Select
    k = Sheets("Associates").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    k = k - 2
    ReDim abc(k)
    
    abc(0) = ""
    
    q = 0
    
    For i = 2 To k + 2
        abc(q) = Cells(i, 1).Value
        q = q + 1
    Next i
    
    Sheets("Main").Select
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err.Number > 0 Then Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set myNameSPace = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    'NextRow = 5
    
    'Starting multiple associates loop
    i = 0
    
    For i = 0 To k
    
    Set myRecipient = myNameSPace.CreateRecipient(abc(i))

    myRecipient.Resolve

    If myRecipient.Resolved Then
     Set CalendarFolder = myNameSPace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar)
    End If
    
    q = Sheets("Main").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    q = q + 1
    
    If q = 2 Then
     q = q + 3
    End If
    
    NextRow = q

    With Sheets("Main") 'Change the name of the sheet here
        .Range("A4:E4").Value = Array("Project", "Date", "Time spent", "Location", "User Email")
        For Each olApt In CalendarFolder.Items
            If (olApt.Start >= FromDate And olApt.Start <= ToDate) Then
                .Cells(NextRow, "A").Value = olApt.Subject
                .Cells(NextRow, "B").Value = CDate(olApt.Start)
                .Cells(NextRow, "C").Value = olApt.End - olApt.Start
                .Cells(NextRow, "C").NumberFormat = "HH:MM:SS"
                .Cells(NextRow, "D").Value = olApt.Location
                .Cells(NextRow, "E").Value = abc(i)
                NextRow = NextRow + 1
            Else
            End If
        Next olApt
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

    Set olApt = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    
    Next i
    MsgBox ("Process Complete.")
    
End Sub
```

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciative

Answer (score 0):

We solved it and all it required was a small change this line:
`

```
Set CalendarFolder = myNameSPace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar`)
```

All we had to do was to prefix: "olFolderCalendar" with "outlook.olFolderCalendar"

```
Set CalendarFolder = myNameSPace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, outlook. olFolderCalendar)
```